# What are the differences in sorting of special characters and numbers between SQLite and H2 databases when using order by?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-order-by, h2

How would SQLite and H2 sort the values 1, 5, @?

Answer (score 0):

SQLite: By default, SQLite places numbers before special characters in sorting. For example, given the values 1, @, and 5, SQLite would order them as 1, 5, @.

H2: In contrast to SQLite, H2 database orders special characters before numbers in its default sorting behavior. For instance, with the values 1, @, and 5, H2 would order them as @, 1, 5.

It's important to note that default sorting behavior can be influenced by collation settings and locale configurations. In my testing, the default collation used by H2 was DEFAULT_EN.

Comment: You are wrong: https://dbfiddle.uk/B_xMhSMG

Comment: So SQLite seems to order some special character like @ after numbers, like in my answer, but there are special characters like / that are ordered before numbers? Do you have any further explanation/documentation at hand?